# Symfony3 Form EntityType

Tags: forms, symfony

I am using Symfony3, getting following error when creating form for EntityType::class

My entity namespace
Project\CoreBundle\Entity\CountryEntity

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Name *', 'attr' => ['data-help'  => 'enter language name here.']])
        ->add('iso', TextType::class, ['label' => 'ISO *', 'attr' => ['data-help'  => 'enter language code here.']])
        ->add('defaultLanguage', EntityType::class,
            array(
                'class' => 'Project\CoreBundle\Entity\CountryEntity'
            )
        )
        ->getForm();
    ;
}
```

Throws Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Project\CoreBundle\Entity\CountryEntity could not be converted to string

Any help will be useful, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as EntityType is an extension of ChoiceType, it needs to know how to render your entity to the form. If you do not pass any information it will try to use the `__toString()` method. If it is not defined, you'll get this error.

Instead of implementing `__toString()`, you may specify the `choice_label` option for your field, which should be a path specification to a property, that should be shown. For example, your `CountryEntity` class may have a `name` property:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Name *', 'attr' => ['data-help'  => 'enter language name here.']])
        ->add('iso', TextType::class, ['label' => 'ISO *', 'attr' => ['data-help'  => 'enter language code here.']])
        ->add('defaultLanguage', EntityType::class,
            array(
                'class' => 'Project\CoreBundle\Entity\CountryEntity',
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            )
        )
        ->getForm();
    ;
}
```

See also `EntityType`'s documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html.

Best regards